# xcode 5.0.2 simulator not reflecting changed in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, ios-simulator

No matter what I do my simulator is not showing the storyboard, just a white bank screen. I did everything. Reset the simulator.Downloaded new ones. Reinstalled mavericks completely and it still doesn't do anything. This is all I can see: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.

I don't know what to do. I renewed my profiles and certificates. Enabled developer mode. Nothing. What can i do?

Comment: When I delete the app from the simulator, I get this code line highlighted in green:  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));   Thread 1:signal SIGKILL

Answer (score 0):

Would you please check your Information Plist File usually present with the name **Projectname-Info.plist** and check whether the value for the property **Main storyboard file base name** is set to your storyboardname. [image]

In the file inspector bottomleft corner search for Info.plist and the edit the property highlighted in the image.

Comment: Sorry if I seem like a beginner but how exactly do I do that? I set the main interface as the storyboard name already. Thanks